# Tomcat Server : Excel Export fails on wire but works on wireless connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, networking, amazon-elb, connection-timeout

Trying to export to excel from webapp hosted on tomcat and Amazon cloud, which works on wireless but fails on wire...what could be reason for such behavior?

**TCPDUMP SNAPSHOT ( FAILS on WIRE )**
[image]

**TCPDUMP SNAPSHOT ( WORKS on WIRELESS )**
[image]

Kindly advice what could be causing timeouts for the same server/client/browser on wired network ? ( while it works on wireless network )

Comment: Any help here would be much appreciated